# File permission issue with Mac/Windows when using git

Tags: windows, git, macos, file-permissions

I ran the following code to pull files from windows git repository.

```
git pull /Volumes/sucho/Desktop/git/setup
```

And I connect the Windows directory as follows.

```
tell application "Finder"
    mount volume "cifs://WINDOWS/c$/Users/sucho" as user name "USR" with password "PW"
end tell
```

It works well, but the problem is the pulled files from windows have 700 (rwx------). How can I set it 644(rw-r--r--) as default?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't really answering your original question, but I hope to highlight another issue I ran into when attempting to trying @drewag's proposed solution...

Another issue I ran into when attempting to ignore file permissions, regardless of whether it was on a Windows or Mac machine (more prevelant on the Windows machine!), was the problem global vs. project-level configurations.

Running this command **did not** affect the .gitconfig file in my *C:\Users\Username* folder:

```
 git config core.filemode false
```

Although adding the *--global* flag **did** affect the change I was looking for:

```
 git config --global core.filemode false
```

Hope this helps someone solve some of their headaches!

Comment: Note: without the global argument this will only affect the project you are currently in. Only specify the --global argument if you are ok with ignoring file permissions on all projects.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't care about file permissions, you can just tell your repository to ignore file permission:

```
git config core.filemode false
```