# How to setup PC and Mac for using git

Tags: windows, git, ssh, cygwin

I use git both for Mac and PC.

When pulling Mac's git from PC, it's easy as I can use ssh.

```
git clone smcho@prosseek:~/smcho/setup
```

The problem happens the other way round : to pull from Mac. I guess there are two ways to go.

#### Method 1 : Connect to server

By using 'connect to server' in Mac, I can make PC's directory like that of Mac. Even though, the [file permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3603476/file-permission-issue-with-mac-windows-when-using-git) issue, it works pretty well.

#### Method 2 : ssh

I could run cygwin ssh server (cygrunsrv -S sshd) to be accessed from other computers, but for me, I have to wait quite a while to get connection as I explained [here](https://superuser.com/questions/110160/ssh-to-cygwin-is-slow-to-respond). It's almost impossible for to use it with git, as I don't want to wait for minutes to get clone.

Here comes my question.

- Is there any better way other than the previous two methods?
- Is there a (natural) way to support ssh server from Windows (windows 7 precisely) not using cygwin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is even another option:

If you use both computers for developing and just want to keep the repositories in sync, you could create a bare repository and use something like Dropbox to synchronize it.

Comment: Has this worked for you?  Leaving my repository sync'ing to drop box would make me very nervous.

Comment: @Alan Jackson: Actually I have not tried it yet, but I plan to do it (I read some articles that proposed this setup). Note that mentioned to use a bare repository, not a "normal" one (so it would be your private "GitHub" repository without GitHub ;)). Otherwise the files get up-/downloaded every time you do a checkout. But if one doesn't care... Dropbox seems to be pretty reliable, why would you be nervous?

Answer (score 3):

I've started using the philosophy of trying to stick in the native environment that something is designed for.

With that in mind, my windows box has an **ubuntu server virtual machine** that hosts my git repositories.  The nice thing is the linux + virtual box + git is an awesome source repository that is completely free.  No extra machine and you can give it very little memory so it isn't a resource hog.

Answer (score 2):

I see two other solutions :

- using a third synchronisation server: [GitHub](https://github.com/), the most famous (if your program is OpenSource), but you can also find [free online private Git repositories](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/GitHosting)
- on Windows, you can set up the Git server ('git daemon' command). On MAC, you'll access to the Windows repository using the URL git://ip_of_windows_machine/repository/

Answer (score 1):

You might consider another approach entirely.  If you're using git as a revision control system that you might consider a hosted account for mastering your repository, maintaining backups, etc.  http://github.com/ is the leader in the space for git.