# How to setup Git on a Mac with Windows 8 running in Parallels

Tags: windows, macos, git, parallels

I'm wondering what is the best way to setup Git on a Macbook Pro both OS X Mountain Lion 10.8 with Windows 8 Pro in Parallels?

I'm not too sure what is the best work flow. Should I be installing Git on both platforms or should I have all my files stored on one platform and install Git just on that?

The reason why I'm asking is because I intend to use Visual Studio on Windows for school projects and use Sublime Text/XCode to work on web development and iOS apps.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to install Git on both workstations, each of them with a full repo.
Ideally, you would push from either workstation to a git repo hosting service like GitHub.

That way:

- you get the full repo (with the full history for all files) on each computer
- you can work on either one of them even without network
- you can save your work on the cloud

The issue can be around setting.
See:

- "[File permission issue with Mac/Windows when using git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3603476/file-permission-issue-with-mac-windows-when-using-git)":
  `git config --global core.filemode false`
- "[Git (GitHub): Multiplatform development and autocrlf option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12031212/git-github-multiplatform-development-and-autocrlf-option)"
  You can set `autocrlf` to `true` on OS X as well as on Windows in your case.
  (even though [I prefer it set to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825428/why-should-i-use-core-autocrlf-true-in-git))

Comment: Thanks but just to clarify something - should I have two different path for my local repository or should I just make it the same path?

Comment: @StevenChen no, each local repo can be anywhere you want on each local machine.