# Convert git repo to submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

So I am fairly new to the whole `git` topic. But what I am trying to do is syncing my `dotfiles` across multiple machines. I know there are plenty of tutorials out there and I got the basic concept. But my question is a tick more specific.

First things first: I am using Windows (for now) and `Vim`. On top of that I use `vundle` to manage my plugins. Now the plugins are `git-repos` themselves. The directory `~/.vim` (which is the main repo I want to sync) contains them.

So my question is, how do I initialize a `submodule` of an existing repo?

What I got now is a bunch of green folders in my `~/.vim/bundle/...` which represent the other repos. The `git status` command reports them as *untracked content* (and no its not my `.gitignore` doing some funky stuff).

You might want to take a look at my repo if you are unfamiliar with the green folder "[phenomenon](https://github.com/tairun/dotfiles.test)".

P.S. One of the subfolders says *modified content* instead of *untracked content*, even though I didn't touch it. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 5):

If all of your bundles are just basic clones with no modifications, you can do something like this: From the root of your dotfiles repo:

```
for d in `find .vim/bundle/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d`
do
    pushd $d
    export url=$(git config --get remote.origin.url)
    popd
    git submodule add $url $d
done
```

That should work well enough - if any bundle isn't a repository, or if you've added it manually, then it'll just pass over that directory.

Then you can then do a `git submodule foreach git pull` to update them all, and add them to update your dotfiles repo's references.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.  Thanks.  BTW, I also added some checks to make sure that a submodule was a git repo before attempting to add it.  That way I could use it on a folder where some subfolders were repos and some weren't

Answer (score 1):

Each time you see modified content without any explicit modification, check global settings ([`core.autocrlf`, `core.filemode`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13888206/6309)) which can make changes on checkout.)

For each directory within [`.vim/bundle/`](https://github.com/tairun/dotfiles.test/tree/master/.vim/bundle), you need to:

- go to that module: `cd .vim/bundle/aModule`
- initialize a git repo (git init .), commit and push to a new git repo on GitHub
- got back to the parent repo: `cd ..` (you are in `.vim/bundle/`)
- `git submodule add https:///github.com/tairun/aModule aModule` (note that this submodule can [track the latest of a branch, if you want to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9189815/6309))

Then `git submodule update --init --remote`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Needed some time to test everything. So far everything has worked really well, even though I didn't do exactly as you told me to. I am still not familiar with a lot of chained commands like `git submodule update --init --remote`, so I can only guess what they do. I may come back at a later time and share my steps. But basically what I did was (from the top of MY repo) `git submodule add git@github.com:user/repo.git bundle/aBundle`. When I get an `index` error I ran `git rm --cache bundle/aBundle`. From there I'd do a git `submodule update --init`.

Comment: @Sensei: you probably should post that as a separate answer. The question perhaps wasn't entirely clear that your vundle plugins are git repos *cloned from the web*, and you're trying to replace them with a basic submodule.

Answer (score 0):

Because the work seems repetitive for me, I would like to share the following rather long git alias:

```
git config --global alias.convertGitRepoToSubmodule '!f() { if [ "$#" = 0 ]; then echo "Usage: convertGitRepoToSubmodule <submodule_directory...>" >&2; return 1; fi; cd -- "${GIT_PREFIX:-.}"; for i; do origin="$(cd "$i" && git config --get remote.origin.url)"; ( set -x; git submodule add "$origin" "$i"; ); done; }; f'
```

Then just do:

```
git convertgitrepotosubmodule $(find .vim/bundle/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d)
```

and it should call `git submodule add <the origin> <the dir>` on all directories.