# Add recursively git repos in subfolder as submodules

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

Add recursively git repos in subfolder as submodules:

iam looking for a solution to add git repositories as submodules to a folder which is a git repo.

I already have the folder structure and the cloned repositories in the destination folder. All i need is to automate adding those repos in the subfolders as submodules.

there are hundreds of git repos so i want to automate it.

structure: folder 1 & 2 serve as categories.

```
~/gitrepo-main/folder1/folder01/submodule
~/gitrepo-main/folder1/folder02/submodule
~/gitrepo-main/folder2/folder01/submodule
~/gitrepo-main/folder2/folder02/submodule
```

EDIT:

probably found the solution via [Convert git repo to submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16224603/convert-git-repo-to-submodule)

script run from gitrepo-main folder

```
#!/bin/bash
for d in `find folder1/ -maxdepth 3 -mindepth 3 -type d`
do
    pushd $d
    export url=$(git config --get remote.origin.url)
    popd
    git submodule add $url $d
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I already have the folder structure and the cloned repositories in the destination folder.

I thought it would be a problem, but [`git submodule add` man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#git-submodule-add-bltbranchgt-f--force--nameltnamegt--referenceltrepositorygt--depthltdepthgt--ltrepositorygtltpathgt) does mention:

> `<path>` is the relative location for the cloned submodule to exist in the superproject.
>
> - If `<path>` does not exist, then the submodule is created by cloning from the named URL.
> - If `<path>` does exist and is already a valid Git repository, then this is added to the changeset without cloning.

So all you need to do:

- [find all gitlinks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4010165/6309) (if those nested repos are already added to the parent repo with a `git add .` done at its root directory)
- or find all nested repo by looking for any `.git` subfolder within the parent repo.
- query for the remote subrepo url (`git remote -v` within each of those folders).
  Note that you don't have '`cd`' into those subfolders, you can do a:

  ```
  git -C /full/path/of/subrepo remote -v
  ```
- declare that path as submodule

  ```
  git submodule add -- /remote/url/of/subrepo relative/path/of/subrepo
  ```

The OP mentions "[Convert git repo to submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33929889/6309)". Using the -C syntax, that would give:

```
for d in `find .vim/bundle/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d`
do
    export url=$(git -C $d config --get remote.origin.url)
    git submodule add $url $d
done
```

No more pushd/popd.

Comment: thx for your answer, please see my edit - have to rush now, will check back later - regards

Comment: @Aurigae yes, that is the same idea

Comment: @Aurigae I have rewritten it with the -C syntax.

Comment: kk,  so we can closeup the question i guess, tyvm - was pure fluke i came across the linked script. I suggest to leave the QA open as the answer wasnt visible by google in the first place, keywords here should do.